# HtmlUnit Load Facebook Photos

Tags: javascript, java, ajax, facebook, htmlunit

So, I have a project where I need to get the photos from a profile.

I am able to navigate to the photos page of a profile, but I believe the JavaScript is not loading.

I am currently using HtmlUnit but if you know of another Java API that would help I'm all ears.

Basically, when I view Facebook in a normal browser, it will load all of the pages and I can inspect the elements.

When inspecting, there is a div called fbStarGrid and a few other modifiers.  This div contains all the images for a user's profile.

When I use HTMLUnit, I cannot find the div.  I had it print the full page XML to a file, and I found that the div is commented out.  I believe this means the Javascript never ran to load the content.

After browsing a lot of javascript help on SO, I have found a few things that help with debugging but can't seem to fix the problem.

The first thing I've done is create an instance of a JavaScriptJobManager.  I used it to see how much JavaScript is not complete.  After waiting for a while (10+ seconds) it says there are still 3 JS jobs uncomplete.  After a very long time (about 60 seconds), it says there are 2 JS jobs uncomplete.

I do not know what is hanging with those JS jobs.

I get a warning upon page load about application/ld+json not running but I do not believe that part of the website is related to the photos.

Is there something I can do to force the JS to run?  Is there a job it's stuck on and won't proceed to the next job?

I've also wondered if it's an issue with the page not re-syncing.

I've tried two solutions related to this:

Setting the AjaxController to NicelyResynchronizingAjaxController()

```
webClient.setAjaxController(new NicelyResynchronizingAjaxController());
```

And someone suggested creating a custom controller that forces syncing.

```
webClient.setAjaxController(new AjaxController(){
        @Override
        public boolean processSynchron(HtmlPage page, WebRequest request, boolean async)
        {
            return true;
        }
    });
```

Neither of these seemed to effect the page.

If HTMLUnit is not the right library for the job, any other ideas?  I need this to be headless/guiless to run on a linux server.  Java is preferred, but I can switch languages if necessary.

Comment: Don't scrape Facebook because they don't allow it. Use the API

Comment: @WizKid hmm I'll take a look. I thought the API was only for games that use profiles as accounts.